# 'str' object does not support item assignment (Python)

Tags: python

```
def remove_char(text):
    for letter in text[1]:
        text[0] = text[0].replace(letter," ")
    return text[0]
```

This is returning:

```
'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Why?  And how can I make this work?

Comment: `text = text.replace(letter," ")`, you cannot use assignment with a string. Also `for letter in text[1]`  is the same as `text = text.replace(text[1]," ")`

Comment: The exception in other words: A python string is immutable..

Answer (score 4):

In Python, strings are not mutable, which means they cannot be changed. You can, however, replace the whole variable with the new version of the string.

Example:

```
text = ' ' + text[1:] # replaces first character with space
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable. By trying:

```
text[0] = text[0].replace(letter," ")
```

you are trying to access the string and change it, which is disallowed due to the string's immutability. Instead, you can use a `for` loop and some slicing:

```
for i in range(0, len(y)):
    if y[i] == ",":
        print y[i+1:len(y)]
        break
```

You can change the string a variable is assigned to (second piece of code) rather than the string itself (your piece of code).

Comment: hmm, maybe I should have been more clear.  The input (text) is a string that is separated by a comma.  I want to remove all of the letters in the string on the left of the comma when the characters in the string in the right side of the comma appear.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the parameter `text` is a string, the line `for letter in text[1]:` doesn't make much sense to me since `text[1]` is a single character. What's the point of iterating over a one-letter string?

However, if `text` is a **list of strings**, then your function doesn't throw any exceptions, it simply returns the string that results from replacing in the first string (`text[0]`) all the letters of the second string (`text[1]`) by a blank space (`" "`).

The following examples show how `remove_char` works when its argument is a list of strings:

```
In [462]: remove_char(['spam', 'parrot', 'eggs'])
Out[462]: 's  m'

In [463]: remove_char(['bar', 'baz', 'foo'])
Out[463]: '  r'

In [464]: remove_char(['CASE', 'sensitive'])
Out[464]: 'CASE'
```

Perhaps this is not the intended behaviour...